# Setting focus in text box when Kendo Window is opened

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

[In this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/uorYAlr7iGvSn9CZuSsC?p=preview) I'm trying to set the focus on the first field of a `kendo-window` when it is opened (click on the button to open the window). I declared the field with `ViewChild`, however it's `undefined` when the window is opened as when the program starts the window hasn't been created yet.

When I attempt to set the focus, I get `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` (see the console).

Is it possible to reference a variable with `ViewChild` after the window is created? How to set the focus on the first field when the window is opened?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
    <button kendoButton (click)="open()">Open window</button>
    <kendo-window title="Some title" *ngIf="opened" (close)="close()" [width]="450">

        <form class="k-form">
            <input kendoTextBox type="text" name="userId" placeholder="User ID"
                 #userId class="k-textbox" autofocus>
            <input kendoTextBox type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" 
                 #firstName class="k-textbox">
        </form>

        </kendo-window>
      </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public opened = false;

    @ViewChild('userId') uid: ElementRef;

    open(){
      this.opened = true;
      this.uid.nativeElement.focus();
    }

    close(){
      this.opened = false;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Changed the PLUNK to show that `autofocus` does not work the second time the window is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the popup into its own component. I then tried to call `focus()` in that components `ngOnInit()` but still had your problem. Wrapping it into a `setTimeout` with zero ms seemed to have solved it. I simply bind the template variable like you did and call this in the `ngOnInit`

```
@ViewChild('userId') userId: ElementRef;

public ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.userId.nativeElement.select();
    }, 0)
  }
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzw45x)

Comment: I think you forgot to add the `setTimeout` to your Stackblitz, I added it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it did not save the last state. I updated the stackblitz. Happy it helped :)

Comment: The only problem that I have is that I declare the variable as `#userId="ngModel"` instead of simply `#userId`, in that case I get an exception `Cannot read property 'select' of undefined` because `userId` is created as `ngModel` object instead of `ElementRef` and `nativeElement` doesn't exist in `ngModel`, any ideas? I us `ngModel` to add a validation to the field.

Comment: I found a solution: I declared two elements `#userId="ngModel"` and `#focusMe`.

Answer (score 0):

Shoud be enought to set autofocus on the element.

Comment: That didn't work for me, if the window is hidden with ngIf the second time that the window is opened the focus is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I focus on the [TextBoxComponent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/).  Use the [`focus`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/TextBoxComponent/#toc-focus-1) method.

```html
<kendo-floatinglabel text="Username" [style.width.%]="100">
    <kendo-textbox #userNameChild formControlName="Username" name="Username" autocomplete="username">
    </kendo-textbox>
</kendo-floatinglabel>
```

```
import { OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TextBoxComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs";

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("userNameChild", { static: false }) public userNameChild!: TextBoxComponent;

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.userNameChild.focus();
        });
    }
}
```